# Find the Min & the Max of User Input - Python

Tags: python

So far, the program finds the average and prints it out. However, I'm not sure how to include the max & the min.

Need to find the max & the min of the values and minus them before calculating the average.

Question reads: Read in integers until the user enters -1. If there were at least 3 values, show the average excluding the biggest and smallest number. If there are less than 3 values, print nothing.

```
value = int(input("Value: "))
count = 0
sum = 0
max = 0
min = 0

while value != -1:
    sum += value
    count += 1
    value = int(input("Value: "))

if count >= 3:
    average = sum / count
    print ("Middle average =", average - max - min)
```

Comment: How about something that starts with `if value > min: ...` and `if value < max:` in that loop...? :)

Comment: You may be better reading the input into a [list](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) [(python documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), sorting it with [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and reading the last and first value of the list.

Comment: Please avoid using sum, max, and min as variable names as they are also python built-in function names.

Answer (score 0):

You've already declared two integers, `max` and `min`. All that's left is to keep track of them as you input the numbers, updating them with each input.

Here is an implementation. Note I have renamed your `max` and `min` variables as they are the names of builtin functions already.

Also note that initially both `maxValue` and `minValue` are set to the first `value`.

```
value = int(input("Value: "))
count = 0
sum = 0
maxValue = value
minValue = value

while value != -1:
    sum += value
    maxValue = max(maxValue, value)
    minValue = min(minValue, value)
    count += 1
    value = int(input("Value: "))

if count >= 3:
    average = (sum - maxValue - minValue) / (count - 2) # exclude the two values here
    print ("Middle average =", average)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
in_list = []

while True:
    inpt = int(input('Value:'))
    if inpt != -1:
        in_list.append(inpt)
    else:
        break

if len(in_list) >= 3:
    in_list.remove(max(in_list))
    in_list.remove(min(in_list))
    print("Middle average: ", sum(in_list)/len(in_list))
else:
    print('Nothing')
```

Comment: You seems to be a fan of using else: while none actually needed in this code

Comment: Not exactly.. but I thought this question is a beginner level so I wrote answer like wise.